# How to get the line number of an exception in OCaml without debugging symbols?

Tags: ocaml

Is there a good way to get the line number of exception in OCaml without debugging symbols?  Certainly, if we turn on debugging symbols and run with `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`, we can get the backtrace.  However, I don't really need the whole backtrace and I'd like a solution without debugging symbols.  At the moment, we can write code like

```
try
    assert false
with x ->
    failwith (Printexc.to_string x ^ "\nMore useful message")
```

in order to get the file and line number from assert, but this seems awkward.  Is there a better way to get the file and line number of the exception?

Comment: I have a shameless plug here, https://github.com/fxfactorial/podge/blob/master/lib/podge.ml#L310

Comment: Did a little Internet-gardening: the above link, had he made it absolute using the `y` hotkey on GitHub, would have linked to this commit/line: https://github.com/fxfactorial/podge/blob/2467a9ec/lib/podge.ml#L310

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are global symbols `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` that you can use anywhere.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# __FILE__;;
- : string = "//toplevel//"
# __LINE__;;
- : int = 2
#
```

**Update**

As @MartinJambon points out, there is also `__LOC__`, which gives the filename, line number, and character location in one string:

```
# __LOC__;;
- : string = "File \"//toplevel//\", line 2, characters -9--2"
```

**Update 2**

These symbols are defined in the [Stdlib module](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/4.14/api/Stdlib.html) (formerly known as Pervasives). The full list is: `__LOC__`, `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__MODULE__`, `__POS__`, `__LOC_OF__`, `__LINE_OF__`, `__POS_OF__`.

The last three return information about a whole expression rather than just a single location in a file:

```
# __LOC_OF__ (8 * 4);;
- : string * int = ("File \"//toplevel//\", line 2, characters 2-9", 32)
```

Comment: There's also `__LOC__` which combines file, line and character range into one string.