# OCaml: define composite exception type with line number information

Tags: ocaml

I am working on some `OCaml` code and I would like to define a composite exception type; as follows:

```
type exceptbase = string * string
exception UndefinedTyp of exceptbase
```

I would like the first element of such exception to be the [line number information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127574/how-to-get-the-line-number-of-an-exception-in-ocaml-without-debugging-symbols).
However, when I use some exception handling code below, it cannot be compiled.

```
raise UndefinedTyp (__LOC__, "some exception messages")
```

So here are my questions:

1. How to correctly define such composite exception type?
2. Note that since the first element is **always** the `__LOC__`, is there any way I can save the effort and use `__LOC__` to pre-occupy the first element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need some parentheses:

```
# type exceptbase = string * string
  exception UndefinedTyp of exceptbase;;
type exceptbase = string * string
exception UndefinedTyp of exceptbase
# raise (UndefinedTyp (__LOC__, "some exception message"));;
Exception:
UndefinedTyp
 ("File \"//toplevel//\", line 2, characters -13--6",
  "some exception message").
```

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey. So is there any chance that I can use `__LOC__` to "pre-occupy" the first element? Thank you!

Comment: Eventually, I choose to use the exception facilities in `Core` as it provides such functionality already...  Please take a look at the [backtrace](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/error-handling.html) section.

Comment: backtraces are not a Core specificity. You can use them with normal OCaml by either adding `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b` or by setting `Printexc.record_backtraces`.

Answer (score 2):

On the second point, within the vanilla OCaml, I am afraid it is impossible to omit `__LOC__` argument.

But you can write a perprocessor to rewrite `Undefined "some exception message"` to `Undefined (__LOC__, "some exception message")`.  Today we use PPX framework to write such a preprocessor.

BTW, OCaml's exception backtrace contains the location of raised exceptions.  Setting environment variable `OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`, OCaml runtime prints it with source code locations when an uncaught exception terminates the program.  Programatically `Printexc` module provides some APIs to obtain it.

Comment: Thank you! I eventually uses the `Core` provided exception handling.. Please take a look at the [backtrace](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/error-handling.html) section.